# React Native fetch() function gives SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: react-native, post, fetch-api

[image]Anybody please tell me what am i doing wrong here .

P.S. When call the api using POSTMAN it goes through with same data given as RAW/JSON input

Here is the code:`

```
fetch(url,{
            headers:{
                "ContentType": "text/json"
            },
            method:"POST",
            body:{"apiKey": "12345", "clientId": "254455",
             "callerId": "02656708557","CallingAgentNumber": "09547142951",
             "CalledPartyNumber": "0891879567", "callType":"2"}
        }).then(res=>res.json()).then(result=>console.log(result)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

`